# How to get query params after rewrite the URL in nextjs?

Tags: next.js, routes

am using nextjs rewrite method on next.config.js

am rewriting the URL with country code to without country code, because sometimes the URL has a country code and not for sometimes.

```
{

   source: '/:countryCode(\\w{1,2})/:category/:genre',

   destination: `/:category/:genre`,

}
```

after redirecting the URL like this

> http://localhost:8000/uk/theatre/broadway/

But it does not have the country code as query params. It has query params as

```
{category: theatre, genre:brodway}.
```

But it should be as

```
{countrycode:UK,  Category:theatre, genre:brodway}
```